# Numpy apply functions to selected indices of matrix

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

I have two random index generators, from 0 to 3

```
idx_1 = np.random.choice(4, 2, replace=False)
idx_2 = np.setdiff1d(range(4), idx_1)
```

and I have a 3D numpy array, example_array, made of stacking 4 matrices together, and 2 functions , say func1 and func2.

I want to do something like

```
example_array[idx1[0]] = func1(example_array[idx1[0]])
example_array[idx1[1]] = func1(example_array[idx1[1]])
example_array[idx2[0]] = func2(example_array[idx2[0]])
example_array[idx2[1]] = func2(example_array[idx1[0]])
```

What is a fast way of doing that, without explicitly writing them as above?

Comment: What is the output of your functions?  A scalar or another matrix?

Comment: outputs are matrices.

Comment: `example_array[idx1]` produces a new array with first dimension sized by`idx_`.  If your `func1` can work with a 3d array, the problem is trivial.  If it is restricted to 2d, then you have to do some sort of iteration on the 1st dimension, explicit as you do or with a `for i in range():` loop.

Answer (score 1):

What about vectorizing `func1()` and `func2()` so you can do

```
example_array[idx1] = func1(example_array[idx1])
example_array[idx2] = func2(example_array[idx2])
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me later in the code.

Comment: Maybe we could optimize the functions if you showed them